# Ошибка 403 не позволяет скачать файл excel

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет,  я новичок в программировании, подскажите как обойти ошибку 403 используя requests в python 3 для скачивания файла excel??
Адрес url ="https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx"

Большое спасибо

Comment: В вашем вопросе не хватает деталей. Какой именно файл по какой ссылке вы пытаетесь скачать? Как именно? Может у вас ошибка в запросе к серверу?

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 0):

[По мотивам этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden).

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
responce = requests.get("https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx", headers=headers)
if (not responce.ok):
    responce.raise_for_status()
```

Строку User-Agent можете взять из своего браузера, отследив запросы.
[image: Network]

Comment: А поможет ли прокси ?